# Make jPlayer stay at end of track

Tags: audio, html5-audio, jplayer

As demonstrated in the [standard jPlayer demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jPlayer/Q4LMV/), when the track ends, the player resets time to zero. Is there any way to make it stay at the end of the track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ended()` event in conjunction with the `playHead` method to keep the play head at the end when it ends.

Modifying the example, here's what I got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function(event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
                oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/2.1.0/js",
        supplied: "mp3, oga",
        ended : function(){
            console.log("ended");
            $(this).jPlayer("playHead",100);
        }
    });
});                                      
​
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wjsKa/2/
**Reference:** http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle demo. It's a good solution, but I'm hoping there might be a more direct way to configure the player, in case this causes a noticeable flash as it moves from 100% to 0% and back to 100%. Especially as my progress bar is using a CSS animation. But if no other approaches, this is certainly workable.

Comment: Another thing you could do is use the `$.jPlayer.event.timeupdate` event which fires every 250ms. Monitor the current position of the media relative to it's total length. Just before you touch the end, you can stop playing. It will mimic the media ending.

Answer (score 1):

jPlayer is opensource, so you can tweak code as you desire. I suggest getting jquery.jplayer sources and removing lines [973](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/blob/master/jquery.jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js#L973) and [974](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/blob/master/jquery.jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js#L974) from jquery.jplayer.js. Then you just save your own copy and compress it if you desire to do so.

Or you can play around with [_updateInterface](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/blob/master/jquery.jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js#L1230) method so it doesn't move seek bar when called from ["ended" event handler](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/blob/master/jquery.jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js#L964).

Sorry for incomplete answer, can't test it right now.