# jPlayer with Icecast stream: how to play stream from live position (not last position) after pause?

Tags: javascript, jplayer, icecast

I have [a website](http://realbadradio.com/) that plays an [icecast](https://icecast.org/) stream with [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/).

I want the `play` button to always start the stream from the live position (like a radio) instead of picking the stream back up from the last position. Attempted behavior:
`play` plays the stream live > `pause` suspends / discards the stream / optionally stops downloading it > `play` plays the stream from live position / reloads the stream.

There is a way to monitor the current media position with `$.jPlayer.event.timeupdate` as mentioned in [comment on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511039/15493622), and use that to resume playing from the end of the stream.

Alternatively, there must be a way to discard the stream when pausing and then reloading it when hitting `play` again. I think it is what is happening on [this jPlayer demo](https://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-08/). But I don't know how to do that part:

> The error event is used with a check for the URL_NOT_SET error type to jPlayer("setMedia",stream) back to the live-stream again and jPlayer("play") it.

I am new to javascript and can't make it work. I can't find another post of someone trying to do that. I tried with the "playhead" at 100 which does not start the stream at all.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://realbadradio.ddns.net:21000/mpd.mp3"
            })
        },
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

[Here the repo](https://github.com/vesubian/realbadradio.com/blob/main/index.html) to my website for full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36027852/15493622) on a different question related to achieving autoplay in jPlayer.

**SOLUTION**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  const stream = {
    // stream address
    mp3: 'http://realbadradio.ddns.net:21000/mpd.mp3'
  };
  ready = false;
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      ready = true;
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
    },
    pause: function() {
      $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");
    },
    error: function(event) {
      if(ready && event.jPlayer.error.type === $.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {
        // Setup the media stream again and play it.
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
      }
    },
    keyEnabled: true,
    preload: 'none',
  });
});
```